# Performing Viewshed Analysis in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, viewshed

I have a series of observation points with heights specified within a long-integer type field.  Points and DEM are in the same coordinate system.  When I run the Spatial Analyst - Viewshed tool, the output is a DEM rather than a boolean raster.
What is going on?
[image: Input]

[image: Out]

Comment: Where is your output? The displayed raster is the input (StitchedCounties.tif)

Comment: Your tool parameters look correct, as @GISGe says I think we need to see the out too?

Comment: The second picture shows the out. Highlighted layer on the Table of Contents is the one.